# Trying to format based on a due date that is between today and 5 days from now

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I'm trying to set up conditional formatting on a List for Due Dates (SharePoint online).

I can't seem to get the correct code for Due Date is between today and 5 days from now. If I use an arbitrary date for one of the dates it works, but as soon as I add @now + 432000000 (5 days in milliseconds) it doesn't work.

If I use on or before @now + 432000000 it works so the function to calculate the date isn't the problem.

Code below:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "box-sizing": "border-box",
    "padding": "02px",
    "overflow": "hidden",
    "text-overflow": "ellipsis"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": {
      "operator": ":",
      "operands": [
        {
          "operator": "&&",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "!=",
              "operands": [
                "[$FileStatus]",
                "Decided"
              ]
            },
            {
              "operator": "&&",
              "operands": [
                {
                  "operator": "=",
                  "operands": [
                    {
                      "operator": "Date()",
                      "operands": [
                        {
                          "operator": "toDateString()",
                          "operands": [
                            {
                              "operator": "Date()",
                              "operands": [
                                "[$Decision_x0020_Due]"
                              ]
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "operator": "Date()",
                      "operands": [
                        {
                          "operator": "toDateString()",
                          "operands": [
                            {
                              "operator": "Date()",
                              "operands": [
                                "@now"
                              ]
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "operator": "=",
                  "operands": [
                    {
                      "operator": "Date()",
                      "operands": [
                        {
                          "operator": "toDateString()",
                          "operands": [
                            {
                              "operator": "Date()",
                              "operands": [
                                "[$Decision_x0020_Due]"
                              ]
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "operator": "Date()",
                      "operands": [
                        {
                          "operator": "toDateString()",
                          "operands": [
                            {
                              "operator": "Date()",
                              "operands": [
                                "@now + 432000000"
                              ]
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgGold sp-css-borderColor-GoldFont sp-field-fontSizeSmall sp-css-color-GoldFont",
        ""
      ]
    }
  },
  "txtContent": "[$File_x0023_]"
}
```

Comment: Can you explain all your requirements/conditions (add details by editing your original question). JSON you added to your question is messy & not in correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding by looking at your JSON, I think you need JSON like below:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "box-sizing": "border-box",
    "padding": "0 2px",
    "overflow": "hidden",
    "text-overflow": "ellipsis"
  },
  "txtContent": "[$File_x0023_]",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "=if([$FileStatus] != 'Decided' && [$Decision_x0020_Due] >= @now && [$Decision_x0020_Due] < addDays(@now,5),'sp-css-backgroundColor-BgGold sp-css-borderColor-GoldFont sp-field-fontSizeSmall sp-css-color-GoldFont','')"
  }
}
```

**Note**:

1. Use correct internal name of your SharePoint list columns, check [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)
2. You can adjust number of days in `addDays` operator and `<` or `>=` conditions as per your requirements.